# Vue.js Pass Component Data Value to Child Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component `TopBar.vue` and I'm trying to open a modal (a child component `Feedback.vue`).

How do I bind the `showFeedbackModal` property between both components?

I want to make it so that when you click the `<a>` tag with `@click="showFeedbackModal = true` the value `true` gets passed to the `<feedback>` component and the modal is shown.

**TopBar.vue (Main)**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section class="top-bar level">
            <div class="level-left">
                ...

                <ul class="level-item">
                    <li><a @click="showFeedbackModal = true"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Beta Feedback</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            ...           
        </section> 

        <feedback :showFeedbackModal="showFeedbackModal"></feedback>            
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showFeedbackModal: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Feedback.vue (modal)**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="showModal" class="modal is-active">
            <div class="modal-background" @click="showModal = false"></div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="box">
                    This is the feedback content
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="modal-close" @click="showModal = false"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {        
        props: ['showFeedbackModal'],

        data() {
            return {
                showModal: false
            }
        },

        beforeMount() {
            this.showModal = this.showFeedbackModal;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your `showModal` property in the `Feedback` component's `mounted` hook. This means that when the component is mounted to the DOM, the value of `showModal` will be set to whatever `showFeedbackModal` is initially but then won't change if the value of `showFeedbackModal` ever changes.

You should just make `showModal` a prop in your `Feedback` component:

```
export default {        
    props: ['showModal'],
}
```

And then, in your `TopBar` component, you just need to pass the `showFeedbackModal` variable as the value for the `showModal` property:

```
<feedback :showModal="showFeedbackModal"></feedback>
```

---

If you want the `Feedback` modal component to be able to affect its parent component's `showFeedbackModal` variable, you can emit a custom event in the `Feedback` component:

```
<button class="modal-close" @click="$emit('close')"></button>
```

And then update the value of `showFeedbackModal` in the handler for that event:

```
<feedback 
  :showModal="showFeedbackModal" 
  @close="showFeedbackModal = false"
></feedback>
```

Comment: Agh. So close. This makes sense. Let me try it out.

Comment: So the modal will appear. But I get an error when I try closing (by clicking close button or modal background): `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "showModal"`

Comment: You should emit an event and let the parent component handle the data manipulation. See my edit.

Comment: Awesome. Works - thanks for your help! I'm slowly coming to terms. ;)

Comment: Question though - is there anyway to use `$emit` to change the `:showModal="showFeedbackModal"` value back to `FALSE` versus adding  `@close=...`?

Comment: Nope. You can't change the value of a property passed into a component.